# How can I avoid parts of images from getting cut, when performing perspective warping?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, perspectivecamera

I am trying to turn the perspective of an image so that I get a result that gives the front view perspective. I am using cv2.WarpPerspective function. However, on performing warp, some parts of the image are getting cut off. How can I avoid this? An option I thought is to find the transformation matrix for a specific part of the image and then apply that matrix to the whole image. However, that method is not yielding desirable results.

The code I am using is :

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
    img = cv2.imread("drive/My Drive/Images_for_Adarsh/DSC_0690.JPG")

    height,width = 1000,1500
    img = cv2.resize(img,(width,height))

    pts1 = np.float32([[ 250, 0],[1220, 300],[1300, 770],[ 250, 860]])
    pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[width,0],[width,height],[0,height]])
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)


    print(matrix.shape)
    print(matrix)
    imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img,matrix,(width,height))
    cv2_imshow(imgOutput)
    cv2.imwrite("drive/My Drive/PerspectiveWarp-Results1/0690_coarse/0690([[ 250, 0],[1220, 300],[1300, 770],[ 250, 860]]).JPG",imgOutput)
```

The input image:
[image: The input image:]

The warped image:
[image: The warped image:]

Comment: Perspective warping involves mapping a set of input coordinates to a set of output coordinates.  Some output coordinates won't map to valid inputs, so those must either be cropped or filled in with some default value.

Comment: If u see in the input image, there are a lot of square panels. Is it possible that I find the transform matric for one of the square panels, and then apply it to the whole image?

Comment: It does not matter what transform you use.  Some parts of the output simply will map outside the boundaries of the input.  I don't know opencv so I can't say whether it gives you the choice of cropping or default fill.

Comment: Specify a larger output image than the input in the warpPerspective()

Comment: @fmw42,  That is a good idea. I tried giving a larger output image than the input one. However, a problem is that there would be parts in the result where no pixel of the input image maps to it. This would give black regions in the image. What can be done to rectify this? How can we crop out the image so that any black region is removed?

Comment: Make the background transparent where it is black. Threshold the output and put the thresholded result into the alpha channel of the output.

Comment: @fmw42, can u please elaborate a bit more? I don't exactly understand what you said there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way to warp the image in Python/OpenCV and add extra space that will contain more of the input, but have areas outside the input as transparent.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input
img = cv2.imread("building.jpg")

# resize
height,width = 1000,1500
img = cv2.resize(img, (width,height))

# specify conjugate coordinates and shift output on left and top by 500
pts1 = np.float32([[ 250, 0],[1220, 300],[1300, 770],[ 250, 860]])
pts2 = np.float32([[+500,+500],[width+500,+500],[width+500,height+500],[+500,height+500]])

# compute perspective matrix
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

print(matrix.shape)
print(matrix)

# convert image to BGRA with opaque alpha
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

# do perspective transformation setting area outside input to transparent
# extend output size so extended by 500 all around
imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width+1000,height+1000), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0,0))

# resize output, since it is too large to post
imgOutput = cv2.resize(imgOutput, (width,height))
    
# save the warped output
cv2.imwrite("building_warped.png", imgOutput)

# show the result
cv2.imshow("result", imgOutput)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Note: it should be possible to use the matrix to project the input corners to the output domain and compute the required output size to hold all of the warped input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. That cleared up a lot. However, now I have a doubt as to, how can I transform this warped image to get a rectangular image? Is there any way other than cropping?

Comment: If your output coordinates correspond to the corners of the input, then compute the inscribed rectangle from those output corners. I do not know how to do that, but it is likely not so easy. I think cropping is the easiest. But given the warping for this case, doing that would crop off much of the building because the left side is narrower than the right side of the image.

Comment: Hey, I have another doubt. Is there any method which is better compared to cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() and cv2.PerspectiveWarp()? I there any other routine I should follow, or any other library function which would give better results?

Comment: ImageMagick will do the same thing (perspective transform) from control points. But can be set to make the output as big as needed to hold all of the input and do that automatically. Python Wand, uses ImageMagick, so you can do the same in Python. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective and https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/